# spring boot data PropertyReferenceException

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Just about everything I can find says this is a naming issue, most examples of the problem site spelling errors such as firstName being spelt firsttName.

But this is not my problem.

I have cut it down to the bare bones as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface GameRepo extends CrudRepository<Game, Long> {
       Game FindByName(String name);
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "game")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Game {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "game_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "game_seq", sequenceName = "game_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(insertable = false)
    private Date created_date;

    /**
     * Parameterless constructor for hibernate
     */
    public Game() {
    }
}
```

I have another project that is much more complex where everything works fine.
Both use the same spring version 3.1.2 in fact identical poms as I started by copying the POM from the working project.

Both projects use the same instance of Postgres running in Docker.

So the question is - is there a stupid spelling error I have not detected after 4 hours of looking and recording? or what other possibility is there for this error.

Comment: Share the exception stack trace. Also, shouldn't `FindByName` start with lowercase 'f'?

Comment: if you will change repository method name from `FindByName` to `findByName` will it work ? and also add all args constructor for entity class

Comment: 4 hours of checking just about everything I could think but not one did I see the capital F!

Comment: small f and it works, many thanks to Yousaf and Andrei Lisa